# How to get OAuth refresh token for use with EWS

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, office365, exchangewebservices

I am able to use an OAuth token with the EWS managed API, but once the token expires I have to get a new one. Some customers are being prompted every time the token expires.

I am using AcquireTokenSilent and AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth with AcquireTokenInteractive as a fall through. Testing internally and for most customers, AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth gets me a new token without a prompt, but some customers are still hitting the AcquireTokenInteractive every time. If a refresh token is not an option, is there an Azure Active Directory setting preventing some users from using the AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth call?

```
try {
    var t = accounts.Any()
        ? System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => pca.AcquireTokenSilent(ewsScopes, accounts.First()).ExecuteAsync())
        : System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => pca.AcquireTokenByIntegratedWindowsAuth(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync());

    t.Wait();
    token = t.Result;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    var t = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(ewsScopes).ExecuteAsync());
    t.Wait();

    token = t.Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the exception is of the **MsalUiRequiredException** type

Every time that the silent token authentication fails, the MsalUiRequiredException is thrown hence you know that for some reason the token couldn't be renewed silently (e.g. the refresh period has elapsed, password has been changed, etc).

Maybe you receive a different kind of exception...